# Automatically add Copyright to new Java files in IntelliJ 12

Tags: intellij-idea

I have registered a Copyright profile in preferences and set it as the default. I also have a scope registered for that profile set to "All". I can add it to a file by doing "cmd+N (generate) -> Copyright".

I don't want to have to do this manually for every new class I create. how can I have this automatically added to all new classes from now on?

Comment: What was missing for me: if you want to only add it to "\*.java" files, create a custom scope with a Pattern of "file:\*.java".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<s>Copyright is not added automatically to the new files</s>, you can use the **Update Copyright** action on the project root node in the Project View to add/update it for all the files at once or you can enable **Update Copyright** option in the `Commit Project` dialog to be sure that files shared via VCS always have the most recent copyright.

**UPDATE**: I've verified that **copyright is added automatically** for me, however it may be hard to notice that it was actually added as by default it appears at the very top of the file and is collapsed, editor also doesn't scroll to the top and remains where it was. If you scroll editor up and unfold the top comment, you should be able to see the automatically added copyright. You can also change the **Location in files** setting per file type to see that it's added when the new file is created.

[Here is the screencast](http://www.screenr.com/D0h7) showing that it works.

Comment: Do you know the reason for this? This seems rather error prone. It's very likely that I will forget to click on "Update Copyright" or add it when committing.

Comment: I think the current way of doing this is pretty easy. An automatism isn't really needed, but would be a nice feature indeed.

Comment: Many thanks @CrazyCoder for the screencast. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me. I've created the same video as you, but I don't get the copyright added: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNGQATfkTKE You may want to watch it in 1080p as it's not really viewable in the default res. Cheers!

Comment: Copyright keyword is not specified in your configuration, so IDEA may think that copyright is already present and therefore doesn't add it. Please try to specify some word in this field that is present only in files that already have copyright added. Also check if you can reproduce it in another project.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried this again, but on a different computer and it worked, by following your instructions. I'm yet to understand why it still doesn't work on the first computer. I should be able to figure it out myself now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same here. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @CrazyCoder how do you insert the current year into a comment so you dont have to change the year every year?

Comment: @JasonCrosby `$today.year`

Answer (score 27):

You have to set the Default Project Copyright for your project.

Go to `File | Settings | Editor | Copyright`, after you have made a new `Copyright Profile`, you must select it from the drop-down list as the `Default project copyright`.

You have to set this for every project, but once it is set, it should automatically be inserted at the top of every new file created in that project.

Answer (score 10):

Go to **File->Settings->Copyrights->Copyright Profiles** and add a new copyright profile. Validate it and click **Apply**, as in the below image,

[image]

Then go to **File->Settings->Copyright** and select newly entered profile as **Default project copyright** and click **OK**, as in the below image

[image]

More information can be found in [IntelliJ IDEA Setup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/generating-and-updating-copyright-notice.html).
(This should work now. If the copyright still not coming automatically to files, enter **"Alt+Insert"** and select copyright)

Answer (score 8):

**This might lead to Duplicate Copyright messages, if there is one already in the file.** *If you don't have existing comments(or you are ok with over writing them) & are in hurry to put comments in, here is a quick way to get them in.*

**Note: *Used on Android Studio***

[image: Running Copyright across Package]

Referenced: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/generating-and-updating-copyright-notice.html#d1722070e316 look for **To update a copyright notice**

Comment: This works on IntelliJ too, quite useful to update copyright for entire project/module.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IntelliJ 14 or above versions. This is what you need to do.
Go to `File | Setting`. Then select  **File and Code Templates** under **Editor** like shown in below image. 
      [image]. Then add copyright license here as shown. Then click on **Apply** and **OK**.

Comment: This is not the intended way of doing this. The copyright section in the Settings -> Editor exists for a reason.